# A dotplot next to boxplots

Tags: r, boxplot

I am trying to figure out how to plot boxplots and a together in one graph.

Starting with the following:

```
data              <- data.frame(matrix(rexp(50), 50))
colnames(data)[1] <- c("values")
data$s1           <- as.factor(c(rep("AA", 30), rep("AC", 18), rep("CC", 2)))
data$s2           <- as.factor(c(rep("AA", 25), rep("AG", 22), rep("GG", 3)))

boxplot(as.numeric(values)~s1,data=data, outline=F, range=1.5)
boxplot(as.numeric(values)~s2,data=data, outline=F, range=1.5)
```

I nearly get what I want. But since the numbers for the CC and GG group are small, I was adviced to plot only the 2 or 3 dots for the CC and GG group respectively.

Or maybe would it be better to do a simple chartplot using the previous data? How would this be done?

Comment: Check out the `ggplot2` package. It has great documentation and examples: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
boxplot(as.numeric(values) ~ s1,
        data=subset(data, data$s1=="AA" | data$s1=="AC"))
stripchart(as.numeric(values) ~ s1,
           data=data, add=TRUE, vertical=TRUE, pch=1, lwd=1)

boxplot(as.numeric(values) ~ s2,
        data=subset(data, data$s1=="AA" | data$s1=="AG"))
stripchart(as.numeric(values) ~ s2,
           data=data, add=TRUE, vertical=TRUE, pch=1, lwd=1)
```

Giving something like this:[image]